# A question on limits of resistor vaules in an op-amp input

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

Here below is a non inverting adder where the resistors R1 and R2 are preventing the loading of V1 and V2. But when determining their size there is a limit as far as I read.

[image]

When reading a comment on sizing resistors for the above circuit, it was mentioned that 10-100 kΩ will be good value for most cases. It is mentioned that if we make R1 or R2 too high, the node on pin 3 will too easily pick up stray noise. What is meant by *stray noise* here and why the high R1 or R2 had a bad effect? Is there a way to explain this in a simple model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stray noise is voltages and currents induced in the wires due to electromagnetic waves that are all around us. Stray noise can come from external to the board, but it can also come from within the system. Logic gates and drivers switching etc.

When such noise is in the vicinity of a wire it will try to induce a voltage in it. If the wire has a high resistance to your ground reference, the voltage the noise can create is significantly larger than a wire with a lower resistance.

The input of the amplifier is high impedance. If R1 and R2 are also high impedance that makes it is easier for electric fields to generate voltages on your input and interfere with your circuit.

That can be illustrated as below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGsGqn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can see that that noise has two opportunities to enter your signal path, before and after the input resistor.

Ideally the source impedance of whatever is driving your circuit should be quite low. This is the case for the output of most op-amps. With a low input impedance driver the voltage divider of the noise on the left side does not leave much voltage noise on the left side of R_Input.

If your source impedance is higher, that is, from some sensor, voltage divider etc. Then significantly more noise will appear on that side. That is why it is important to keep the sensor as close to the first input pin as you can, use twisted pair wires, shielding etc, or to actually add a unity gain buffer close to the sensor.

With no feedback on it, the op-amp input pin impedance is normally very high impedance. If R_Input is high the voltage divider on the right leaves significantly more noise on the right side of R_Input.

The worst case would be leaving the resisters out entirely. "Infinite resistance" (Not really but we will go with that for this argument.) At which point your trace becomes a nice little antenna.

**ADDITION: The OTHER reason to use lower values.**

Not shown on most schematics because it is not an actual part is trace impedance between the trace and ground. This is mostly capacitive and resistive but also has an inductive part too, especially on long traces and wires.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNztF2.png)</sup>

As you can see that creates a low-pass filter on your signal. The higher the input resistor value you chose the more you will cut off the higher frequencies of your signal.

Because it is an impedance there is also some signal loss due to the resistive part. The bigger your input resistor the more the loss.

**The Balance.**

From the above you can see high value resistors add all kinds of issues. Lower is better. However, low value resistors also means more current consumption since your drivers need to work harder. The trick then is to balance the trade-off between noise and frequency response performance against acceptable power usage.

Comment: Thanks, as you say the input of the amplifier is high impedance. Lets say it is 20Meg and if R1 is 10k the total resistance that the noise will hit onto will be  (20Meg+10k); but if the R1 is 10Meg the total resistance the noise will hit onto will be 30Meg. So in the second case the induced voltage noise will be higher. Is that the basic logic behind? Just want to be sure if I understand what you meant.

Comment: @doncarlos almost.. the resistors are effectively in parallel not in series as you imagined and the 10K is actually a bit more than that since you need to add in the output impedance of whatever is driving it. The latter is usually low though if it is an active gate.

Comment: sorry didnt get two points: "resistors are effectively in parallel not in series" which resistors are in parallel? amplifier's high input impedance and R1? and "The latter is usually low" what is "latter"? thanks

Comment: @doncarlos I expanded my answer, hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: amazing explanation

Comment: Isn't it more accurate to say that a current is induced in the conductor? Then the reason for higher noise voltage with a higher resistance is easily seen with V=IR.

Comment: @AndrewMorton the noise voltage induces the current though. But that's a circular argument and a road I'd rather not go down here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a gain-of-10X opamp circuit, with 1milliVoltPeakPeak input coming through a 5MegOhm resistor. This tool includes builtin databases of interferers; in the Gargoyles mode, I've selected ONLY the Electric Field interferer, which is a MicroController Clock at 1mm distance.

With no interference and no source resistor, the SNR (remember, desired signal is only 1mVpp) is +44dB. With the Rsource set to 5MegaOhms, SNR falls to +15dB. And with the first database entry Efield interferer activated, SNR falls again to +13dB. In other words, the MicroController Clock energy was worse than the thermal noise of the 5MegOhm Rsource.

[image]

Next, here is revised Signal Chain: still 1 milliVoltPP input *but* Rsource now is 10KOhm. Because that resistor (as did the 5MegaOhm) provides thermal noise, I've included the Thermal Noise plot in screenshot.

Because its easy to turn on more Efield aggressors, I've left enabled the MCU clock, and added 60Hz and 60Hz_with_spikes (often from fluorescent lights).

In this new circuit, with Rsource = ZERO, SNR is 44dB. With Rsource = 10Kohm, SNR is 36dB. And with three Efield aggressors enabled, and "gargoyles" enabled, SNR is 12 dB. View the contributions of 3 Efield interferers at topleft in table form. [ by the way, with MCU Clock as only Efield aggressor, SNR is 21 dB]

[image]

If you click on top-middle "show interconnects", you can edit the PCB traces; changing the Length and Width changes the area into which Efields couple. 
Here is the topology of Efield injection:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f57QZp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice the capacitors in series; at high frequencies the Efield aggressor is attenuated by this capacitive divider.

Also notice the Rsource and Rin of Opamp; at low frequencies, the series C from Efield source forms a High Pass Filter.

Comment: interesting tool and proves that the induced noise is increasing with the source resistor value. it would be great if you would show the result for a 10k resistor which is a typical value.

Comment: The tool is free to download and use. The 4 aggressor databases contain: Efields, Hfields, VDD_trash 60Hz to 300MHz FPGA ringing, and GND trash (motors, etc). You can add new entries to each of the 4 databases, or edit the initially provided entries. I've reduced the Rsource to 10Kohms, as you requested. By the way, the TRACE MODEL of PCB signal area is how Efields couple into the circuit. Default PCB area is 14mm by 1mm, editable in the Wiring Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, that VDD pin is another point for "noise" to enter the OpAmp

[image]
Hence you must also DESIGN the VDD filtering. Simply sharing the VDD with the FPGA......not a good idea.

Comment: is there a tutorial how to learn to use this tool?

Comment: on the website "robustcircuitdesign.com", look under WhitePapers. You'll see the paper "Managing Interferers in a 12-bit Signal Chain", which shows how to build a signal chain and activate the interferers, and then reduce the effect of interference. And there are various recent blog content, showing useful features. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Primary skill you need: select type of stage on left, scroll down and double-click on the stage you want to insert. Click "update" on right, to get latest BODE and SNR/ENOB, etc.